# Android emulator error application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

Why when I start the emulator on Nexus S API 25 app is running.
But when I started Nexus 5X API 25x86 said application had stopped?

`logcat`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.name.projectname, PID: 3269 java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(112896000bytes) bitmap. at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayList‌​Canvas.java:260) at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
```

How can I solve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: What does `logcat` say?

Comment: please show logcat

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.name.projectname, PID: 3269
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(112896000bytes) bitmap.
at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)